# Looking for derivation of Shannon entropy of binomial distribution

Tags: references, binomial-distribution, entropy, information-theory

According to Wikipedia, the Shannon entropy of a binomial distribution is $\frac{1}{2}log_2 (2\pi*e* np(1-p)) + O(1/n)$  Does anyone know where I can find a derivation?

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/244764/152225)?

Comment: Found a solution [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/244764/152225), thanks Antoni.